# How to deny access from Windows 7 to a Windows 8.1 drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, password-protection

I have dual-boot with Windows 7 installed on one partition of my hard drive and Windows 8.1 installed on the other partition. How to deny Windows 7 users access to the Windows 8.1 partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real solution is full disk encryption. I would go with BitLocker.

Comment: Should I encrypt Windows 8.1 partition after booting into Windows 8.1 or Windows 7?

Comment: You need to enable BitLocker from the OS you are going to encrypt. Your Windows 7 won't be participating or affected.